# Wordpress: Generate A "Hierarchical" List Of Links Of A Post's Categories

Tags: wordpress, post, hierarchy, categories

Seems like a simple task but I have been all over the WordpressCodex and numerous tutorials with no luck.

I want to generate a list of links, with a bullet point separator, of a post's categories, in hierarchical, not alphabetical, order.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're after..?

http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories#Display_Categories_Assigned_to_a_Post

Bullet points can be added with css.

Comment: Yes that appears to be what I want however, adding the code as-is does not echo out anything. As I mentioned in my question, I have already been all over the Wordpress Codex and tried every available option. If you can figure out how to make this one work that would be great.

Comment: If you check the arguments you'll see it says echo=0, so change the zero to a 1 and see if that helps...

Answer (score 0):

Final solution :

Just put a below code:

```
    <?php 
    $args = array(
      'orderby' => 'id',
      'hide_empty'=> 0,
      'child_of' => 0, //Child From Boxes Category 
  );
  $categories = get_categories($args);
  foreach ($categories as $cat) {        
        echo '<li>'.$cat->name.'</li>';
    }
?>
```

Thanks.

Comment: get_the_category_list(); give me a list of post categories...however it does not order them hierarchical with the parent first, first child next, and second child after that etc...

Each post has a structure like this:

Parent >
    First Child >
        Second Child >

Comment: so how would like to get them all..? in a single list...? or 1st category then next its child category if it have with a tab and all..?

Comment: Yes hierarchical order meaning the top level category first (parent), then the next level down (child of parent), then the next level from from that (child of child).

Comment: thanks for the help but ordering by ID does not work as the categories we're created at various times so the ID is not in hierarchical order. I read something about an argument called hierarchical => 1 but I have not been able to get it working

Comment: this one shows exactly like in categories page...? now how would like to see.?

Comment: hierarchical order, where order is decided by the hierarchy of the categories based on their parent-child relationship. if we order by ID and the parent was created after the child the order will not be correct as the ID number for the parent will be higher than the ID number for the child.

Comment: Try `'orderby'=> 'term_group'` instead..?